# Trying to convince a coworker to NOT use entity-attribute-value (EAV)

Tags: postgresql, entity-attribute-value

They really like the flexibility of it, being able to make a database update and then allow your users to collect a new data point. I've sent them

https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/03/database-modelization-anti-patterns/#entity-attribute-values
And
https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/entity-attribute-value-eav-design-in-postgresql-dont-do-it/

I'm trying to emphasize that I like reporting to remain easy and efficient, and being able to do constraints and basically use an RDS etc...

The attributes are not many and I don't see them needing more daily, maybe adding one or two quarterly. I've trying to stave off the 'pre-optimization' of basically if we do EAV the problem is solved.

One annoyance is having to update the client code if a new column was added, I've been pondering offering a dynamic postgres function that could just insert a value into a user defined column as kindof a compromise.

Any other good articles or advice are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You have to rebuild all database technology, like concurrency, constraints, data integrity, etc. in your application. Using EAV you don't have data types anymore, so 1 and one will be both valid for a number. Just like banana.

I have seen successful EAV implementations, but only for reporting databases where there was no concurrency and all constraints and data integrity was handled in the main production (OLTP) database.

> One annoyance is having to update the client code if a new column was
> added

You have to update the client code anyway. There is no code in the world that knows what to do when a new attribute suddenly pops up in the database.

Comment: Using EAV you could populate a drop down from the database of possible values, and then record against that type. This is the sort of ease-of-use they are arguing for

Comment: So you don't need a database at all, any configuration file can offer that functionality.